# choosing a synonym of "wind" in my song

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, poetry

I'm writing words to a song, and I'm hesitating between some synonyms for "wind" (I'm writing the lyrics here, context is me being alone at night in an old remote mansion) :

"Late last night lke the night before I heard some knocking at my door
Was it just the (or "a") [wind] blowing through the woods"

I thought about "gale" (my favourite) or "gust".. do they apply correctly to the context? What ideas do they convey?

I was also thinking of replacing "blowing" by "swerving"; does it make sense or is it too weird?

Thank you

Comment: You can call the wind "Mariah".

Comment: Also, when the wind comes through the woods, it sings, moans, whistles... and, yeah, "swerving" is weird.

Comment: Why do you want to use a synonym for "wind"? A "gale" is a storm wind. (There's a famous actress whose stage name was Gale Storm.) A "gust" does not typically appear alone; it's "a gust of wind".

Comment: Did you Google "synonym wind"?

Comment: Get rid of blow, for sure.  I'm not too sure about wood either.  Also, you don't have a door, she does.  You are the keymaster, not the gatekeeper.  You have outie, she has innie.  You do not think of her among (other) wood, you think of her in a sushi bar and you appear there as bamboo.

Answer (score 2):

*Gale* and *gust* have powerful connotations(as opposed to breeze, which is a softer and gentler blow of air). It's perfectly alright to use *gale* or *gust* if you're convinced that they bring the required effect to the song.

**Zephyr**: a soft gentle breeze.

- *Was it just the **zephyr** blowing through the woods*

(I know it sounds odd...)

- *Was it just **a puff of wind**(similar to breeze)...*

**Chinook**: a warm dry wind which blows down the east side of the Rocky Mountains at the end of winter.

> Chinook is claimed by popular folk-etymology to mean "snow-eater", but it is really the name of the people in the region where the usage was first derived. The reference to a wind or weather system, simply "a Chinook", originally meant a warming wind from the ocean into the interior regions of the Northwest of the USA (the Chinook people lived near the ocean, along the lower Columbia River). A strong Chinook can make snow one foot deep almost vanish in one day.

Source: Wikipedia

Check the details before using this word in your song.

- *Was it just the **chinook**...*

Or maybe,

a **roar of wind**(personification that means the same as gust)

- *Was it just the **roar of wind**...*
- *Was it just the **breath of Aeolus***(God and Ruler of the Winds in Greek mythology) that gushed through the woods

You can probably modify *breath of Aeolus* to *breath of any [wind deity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wind_deities)*

P.S.: Since you added *poetry* as a tag, I got slightly confused. It makes sense to use personifications and other figures of speech in poetry(but I'm not sure if it is okay to do so while composing songs(which are meant to be sung)).

Answer (score 1):

As you are writing song lyrics, you will be seeking words to fit into a rhythm. 
Working on the assumption that the first sentence:

```
'Late last night like the night before,
I heard some knocking at the door.'
```

is split into two equivalent parts (as above), you may intend doing likewise with the second sentence:

```
'Was it [a ghost] or just [the wind],
[whishing] and [whooshing] through the woods?'
```

It can be fun to combine words as, for example:

*'the gale groaning and gusting'*

*'the storm swishing and swooshing'*

*'the wind howling and heaving'*

You can find definitions for the suggested verbs at: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: I like your suggestion to introduce the "ghost" alternative along side the less scary one in the same line!  Anthony could also use this technique to get some alliteration (and use "winding" as a verb to capture the notion of "swerving") as follows: "Was it a ghost or just a gust, winding [its way] through the woods?"

Answer (score 0):

To pick up on your idea of using "swerving" instead of "blowing," you could emphasize the sound of the movement of the trees caused by the wind, instead of mentioning the wind explicitly. One sound that could resemble knocking is the one produced by a tree bending or rubbing against another, so "groaning" or "creaking" would convey the image of a tree being blown by the wind against another, and making that characteristic knocking noise. This is just an indirect way to signal that there is wind involved, yet to focus more on its result, which you want to compare to the sound of a knocking at the door. A specific species of tree could be mentioned for a stronger image, something like: "Or was it just the oaks groaning in the woods?"